# onreadystatechange event function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have started learning HTML Javascript events and I'm confused a little bit. this following function takes event as a parameter however it works well the same without a parameters and I'm wondering how is that happening. when I console.log(event.type); it still shows the readystate event regardless of argument passed in the function

```
document.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    console.log(event.type);
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        console.log("Ready!");
        console.log(document.getElementById("some-div").innerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some browsers have a global variable `event`. But it's not portable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState